# from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'

Tags: python, pycharm

I have installed nltk library in my laptop but when I try to import it in my pycharm project, it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'` . What should I do?
This is my console response when I type `pip3 list`:

```
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
blis              0.2.4
certifi           2019.9.11
chardet           3.0.4
ChatterBot        1.0.5
chatterbot-corpus 1.2.0
cycler            0.10.0
cymem             2.0.3
idna              2.8
kiwisolver        1.1.0
mathparse         0.1.2
matplotlib        3.1.1
MouseInfo         0.1.2
murmurhash        1.0.2
nltk              3.4.5
numpy             1.17.2
opencv-python     4.2.0.32
panda             0.3.1
pandas            0.25.1
Pillow            6.2.0
Pint              0.10.1
pip               20.0.2
plac              0.9.6
preshed           2.0.1
PyAutoGUI         0.9.48
PyGetWindow       0.0.8
pymongo           3.10.1
PyMsgBox          1.0.7
pyparsing         2.4.2
pyperclip         1.7.0
PyRect            0.1.4
PyScreeze         0.1.26
python-dateutil   2.7.5
PyTweening        1.0.3
pytz              2019.2
PyYAML            5.1.2
reportlab         3.5.28
requests          2.22.0
selenium          3.141.0
setuptools        40.8.0
six               1.12.0
spacy             2.1.9
SQLAlchemy        1.2.19
srsly             1.0.1
thinc             7.0.8
tqdm              4.41.1
urllib3           1.25.6
wasabi            0.6.0
xlrd              1.2.0
```

As this shows, nltk is installed but when I run the below code :

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
```

It shows :

```
from nltk.chat.util import Chat, reflections
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'
```

I experienced this same error while using **chatterbot library**. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer!
Just had to install the libraries in my pycharm by:

> File -> Settings( Preferences in mac ) -> Project:yourProjectName -> Project Interpreter -> '+' button on the right side -> type the library name in the search box -> Click install and you are done!